# generate each minute string for a day within specified time limit

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

My aim is to generate per minute count of all records existing in a table like this.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) as RECORD_COUNT,
    to_Char(MY_DATE,'HH24:MI') MINUTE_GAP
FROM
    TABLE_A
WHERE
    BLAH='Blah! Blah!!'
GROUP BY
    to_Char(MY_DATE,'HH24:MI')
```

However, This query doesn't give me the minutes where there were no results.

To get the desired result it, I'm to using the following query to fill the gaps in the original query by doing a JOIN between these two results.

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    (   SELECT
            TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE)+( (ROWNUM-1) /1440) ,'HH24:MI') as MINUTE_GAP,
            0 as COUNT
        FROM
            SOME_LARGE_TABLE_B
        WHERE
            rownum<=1440 
    )
WHERE
    minute_gap>'07:00' /*I want only the data starting from 7:00AM*/
```

This works for me, But

1. I can't rely on **SOME_LARGE_TABLE_B** to generate the minutes
   because it might have no records at some point in future
2. The query doesn't look like a professional solution.

Is there any easier way to do this?

> NOTE:I don't want any new tables created with static values for all the minutes just for one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just generate your timestamps and left join your grouped data to it:

```
SELECT MINUTE, ....
FROM (
    SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE((LEVEL + 419) * 60, 'SSSSS'), 'HH24:MI') MINUTE /* 07:00 - 23:59 */ FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1020)
    LEFT JOIN (
        <your grouped subquery>
    ) ON MINUTE = MINUTE_GAP
```

Comment: You can use recursive subquery with the same result but connect by is shorter and cleaner in this case.